# is username still required if I create customer django user model to use email for authorization

Tags: django, django-models

I am working on creating a custom user model for my django project to use email for authorization.  Can I leave out the username field or is it still required?  I have been searching but it is not clear.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are extending the user modal built into django No. But if your making your own modal extending `models.Model` yes

Comment: Then can I just assign the username to be the email inside the model?  I don't want users to have to two different things.

Comment: well you can use the build in django user model for admins and a custom one for other